# Avoid un-necessary view nest when create custom view together with xml resource

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a custom view, and I extends from `LinearLayout`:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {
    private ImageView mPrevImgView;
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        View root = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        this.addView(root);

        mPrevImgView = root.findViewById(R.id.xx);
        ....
    }
}
```

And the `layout/custom.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/xx"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    .......
</LinearLayout>
```

Then I try to use it this way:

```
<CustomView android:layout_width.....>
  ...
</CustomView>
```

This works as expected.

However it seems that the `CustomView` itself is a `LinearLayout`, and it then add another `LinearLayout` in the constructor, this cause two `LinearLayout` nested which is unnecessary. I wonder if it is possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this way 
**custom.xml**
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/xx"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: There are other views in the xml

Comment: Then you have two option one define individual like above all your views and another is you already do (put your all view under parent layout)